# Using C# and Repository Factory and the error: The requested database is not defined in configuration ? What causes that?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I am using Repository factory for visual studio 2008 for a personal project.
It generated a class called `ProductRepository` which inherits from `Repository<Product>`.
The `ProductRepository` has a constructor which gets a database name as string and passes it to its base (I mean `Repository<Product>` ).

When I try to debug my project step by step, I pass my database name to  `ProductRepository`
but it raises the following error:

> The requested database is not defined in configuration.

What's wrong?

Comment: What framework are you using? What's the specific error message/call stack?

Comment: .Net framework 3.5. I have put exact error message above.

Comment: What framework is your repository from? If it's bespoke, I'm not sure we will have enough knowledge to help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that means it has to do with the configured connectionstring. Check your config.